# C++ char while( str != '\0')

Tags: c++, char, cin

I'm building a very simple program in C++. The program is working like this, you will input some random number(this number can be of any reasonable size) So for example if you input 23215 you will get 87890 as output. But my while statement here "while(str != '\0') aint working like it's supposed to do. Someone knows why? Because from what I know '\0' is the specific symbol for end of a char. (And I know that str is a bad name for a char, I'm to lazy to change that now)

```
int main()
{
char str;
cout << "Enter a coded message: ";
cin >> str;
cout << endl;
cout << "Decoded message: ";
while (str != '\0')
{       
switch (str)
        {
        case '0': cout << "5";
            break;
        case '1': cout << "9";
            break;
        case '2': cout << "8";
            break;
        case '3': cout << "7";
            break;
        case '4': cout << "6";
            break;
        case '5': cout << "0";
            break;
        case '6': cout << "4";
            break;
        case '7': cout << "3";
            break;
        case '8': cout << "2";
            break;
        case '9': cout << "1";
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: What's "not working" about it? What does "working like it's supposed to do" mean to you? Currently you're not actually _using_ the loop construct .. you're just creating an infinite loop (which you did not mention).

Comment: _"Because from what I know '\0' is the specific symbol for end of a char. "_ Sorry but this all looks like guesswork programming to me. Which book are you using?

Comment: Are you too lazy to learn the difference between a char and a string? That after all is the main reason your program doesn't work.

Comment: Ofc I know the difference between char and strings, but I thougt this task was possible to solve with a while loop and chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a a few bugs in your program. A pretty big one is you need to have the user enter a `string` and not a `char`. Take a look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;

    cout << "Enter a coded message: "; 
    cin >> input;

    cout << "Decoded message: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        switch (input[i]) {
            case '0': cout << "5";
                break;
            case '1': cout << "9";
                break;
            case '2': cout << "8";
                break;
            case '3': cout << "7";
                break;
            case '4': cout << "6";
                break;
            case '5': cout << "0";
                break;
            case '6': cout << "4";
                break;
            case '7': cout << "3";
                break;
            case '8': cout << "2";
                break;
            case '9': cout << "1";
                break;
            default: 
                      cout << "X";
                      break;
        }
    } 

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Ofc it's like this, I blame that 6 hours of driving straight ain't the best for your programming ability ;)

Answer (score -1):

> But my while statement here `while(str != '\0')` aint working like it's supposed to do. Someone knows why?

When you read a character from an input stream, it will never be equal to `'\0'`. That's the first error in logic.

Also, you are reading `str` only once. You are not reading anything but the first character of your input.

Change your code to:

```
int main()
{
   int ch;
   cout << "Enter a coded message: ";
   cout << endl;
   cout << "Decoded message: ";
   while ( (ch = cin.get()) != EOF )
   {       
      switch (ch)
```

If you want to stop reading after reading all the characters in the first line, you can use:

```
int main()
{
   int ch;
   cout << "Enter a coded message: ";
   cout << endl;
   cout << "Decoded message: ";
   while ( (ch = cin.get()) != EOF && ch != '\n' )
   {       
      switch (ch)
```